# Comparing mechanical signals with different length

Tags: python, convolution, correlation

I couldn't find any solution for this that would work for me

I'm working in python.

I have two similar signals that I can plot Force x Angle. (problem simplified)

One plot (angle x force) has length 10000 and the other 40000 (hypothesis/problem simplified).

I would like to check for similarity in these two signals in relation to the angle.

My first approach was to try to correlate or convolve with scipy and numpy packages

The problem is that convolve force1 with force2 can be non-sense if they have different lenghts.

What do you think it would be a good strategy to compare both these signals?

Comment: I don't think simplifying at this level is a good idea – you just say "similarity", but that's not really a mathematically quantifiable term; so, maybe do describe your data in more detail (where does it come from?) and what the purpose of your analysis is!

Comment: Is this merely a resampling exercise to get point by point comparative lengths?